# Android Studio 1.5 Opencv 3.0.0 sample camera calibration crashed

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk

I would like to calibrate the camera of my tablet for an android application by using OpenCV 3.0.0 but I've got a error.

- I import the camera-calibration sample
- I took ~10 picture of the chessboard
- I started the calibration and suddenly the apps crashed with this error:

> Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp:77: error: (-215) _tvec.total() * _tvec.channels() == 3 && (_tvec.depth() == CV_32F || _tvec.depth() == CV_64F) in function void cv::fisheye::projectPoints(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, double, cv::OutputArray)

Any ideas? I'm using android studio 1.5.
If you have also an alternative, I'll take it. Thanks in advance.